# Abreviating the for loop in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

Recently, while coding, I've been finding myself writing the exact same for loop header over and over again:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [somevalue]; i++)
{
    [other code]
}
```

Does anybody know of a way to overload the for loop, or define another keyword so that it takes a number and feeds it through a given for loop, to abbreviate for into something like:

```
for ([somevalue])
{
    [other code]
}
```

or

```
nfor ([somevalue])
{
    [other code]
}
```

Because just writing `for(12)` all the time and having it iterate through the code 12 times would be so much nicer

Comment: Depending on what `othercode` is, you might be better off using the algorithms from the C++ Standard Library, such as `for_each` or `transform`.

Comment: IDE's like [eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) have this with code-completion. It fills out the for-loop from a template and you just insert the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or, if you want to use plain old macros, can do

```
#define nfor(somevalue) for(int i = 0; i < somevalue; ++i)
```

Then use it as

```
nfor(10)
{
    cout << "Hello World " << i << "!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: I was about to start writing an answer using lambdas, but this is way simpler and matches the desired syntax.

Comment: well, depends on what you mean by better. lambda approach is pure C++ and doesn't imply the preprocessor, so it is "pure", however this gets the job done fast. however, the lambda approach hides the counter from the loop, unless you make it static

Comment: there's nothing wrong, that's why I posted the answer :) but sometimes it is preferable to avoid using macros if you can (e.g., use `const int x = 10` instead of `#define x 10`) as macros are not type safe etc... however, for the present purpose, I find the macro perfectly acceptable

Comment: That works perfectly. thank you. I suppose the name fori, and a second one forj is more descriptive. I noticed immediately that rereading the code is a bit cryptic and breaks if you nest them.

Comment: @CraigAllen didn't think about nesting, it "breaks" in the sense that cannot access the outer `i`, right (the inner scope hides the outer scope)? cause otherwise it works

Answer (score 6):

You can make your own `for` method that takes a function object:

```c++
template <class F>
void for_t(std::size_t n, F const& f)
{
    while (n--)
        f();
}

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    for_t(5, [&] { std::cout << ++count << " "; });
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 Why introduce the whole scope? just use `[&count]` no point in giving the function access to things it doesn't need.

Comment: @self : As `count` is the only variable in scope, there's nothing else to give access _to_.

Comment: @self, if you want the loop to resemble a `for`, I think 0x49... got it right, as you may want to modify the outside scope, as you would do in a regular `for`

Comment: should this great, convenient method be called ``repeat``?

Comment: @Escualo `for_t` was the first thing that came to me. You may change it to `repeat` if you like.

Answer (score 4):

Or using ranges (and boost):

```
for(int i : boost::counting_range(0, limit))
    /* do nice things */ ;
```

[boost::counting_range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/ranges/counting_range.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
class until {
public:
    until(int limit) : count(limit) {}
    int operator*() const { return count; }
    until &operator++() { ++count; return *this; }
    bool operator!=(const until &rhs) const { return count != rhs.count; }
    until begin() const { return 0; }
    until end() const { return count; };

private:
    int count;
};

#include <iostream>

int main() {    
    for (int count : until(5)) {
        std::cout << count << ' ';
    }
}
```

[N3853: Range-Based For-Loops, The Next Generation](http://isocpp.org/blog/2014/01/n3853) would make `for` terser.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a for loop in C++. There are two ways which might do what you want.

The first is to use the latest addition to the for loop family introduced in C++11.

```
for(int x : (int[12]){}){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Not quite what you want, but still a bit shorter. The other option would be to make your own function, and let it take in a size and a function. 0x499602D2 beat me on that part, so refer to their post for how to on that.

Comment: Seems wasteful to allocate memory (even on the stack) for this purpose, especially if the number of iterations is very large.

Answer (score 0):

E.g. like

```
template< class Func >
void repeat( int const n, Func const& f )
{
    for( int i = 1; i <= n; ++i ) { f(); }
}

void foo()
{
    int n = 1;
    repeat( 12, [&]
    {
        // other code, e.g.
        cout << n++ << endl;
    } );
}
```

Disclaimer: code not touched by compiler's hands.

Answer (score 0):

If you like the macro approach, it might be better to slightly tweak @vsoftco's solution to enable using different name for the loop control variable:

```
#define nfor(varname, somevalue) for(int varname = 0; varname < somevalue; ++varname)
```

This way, you can have nested for loops using above macro:

```
nfor(i, 10)
{
    nfor(j, 10)
    {
        cout << i << " " << j;
    }
}
```